# DB SQL for Vault in corda 3

Tags: corda

In corda open documentation I read the following:

> The ORM mapping is specified using the Java Persistence API (JPA) as annotations and is converted to database table rows by the node automatically every time a state is recorded in the node’s local vault as part of a transaction.
>
> > Presently the node includes an instance of the H2 database but any database that supports JDBC is a candidate and the node will in the future support a range of database implementations via their JDBC drivers. Much of the node internal state is also persisted there.

Can I replace h2 DB with an SQL one using JDBC?

As I understood, the FinalityFlow is used to record the transaction in the local Vault using h2 DB.
If I implement a custom Flow to record in an SQL DB, i have to avoid the FinalityFlow call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to run a node with a SQL database other than H2. In fact, support for PostgreSQL and SQLServer has been contributed by the open-source community. See the set-up instructions [here](https://docs.corda.net/head/node-database.html). However, be aware that the Corda continuous integration pipeline does not run unit tests or integration tests of these databases, so they must be used at your own risk.

Note that in both cases, you configure the node to use the alternative database via the configuration file, and it stores all its data in this alternative database (transactions, states, identities, etc.). You are not expected to access the database directly in a flow to do this, and can rely upon the standard `ServiceHub` operations and standard flows like `FinalityFlow`.

Comment: Are there any naming convention for nodes when using postgres configuration? I cannot figure out why when I call a node with "Notary" or "Broker" i receive the error: `Database connection url is : jdbc:h2:tcp://192.168.56.1:62412/node E 11:08:27+0200 [main] util.PropertyElf.setProperty - Failed to set property url on target class org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource {}`. I had to rename the nome in "MyNotary" and "MyBroker" to resolve. It seems that it wasn't getting the correct jdbc.